# clinfo clGetPlatformIDs error with AMD APP SDK

Tags: opencl, ubuntu-14.04, amd-gpu

I had install AMD APP SDK-3.0 for my laptop with Intel i5 3rd generation configuration. I have no GPU other than my Intel processor's builtin graphics.
I had installed the SDK in the below way:
`./AMD-APP-SDK-v3.0.130.136-GA-linux64.sh`.
My `.bashrc` file has:

```
**export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/roadeo/AMDAPPSDK-3.0/lib/x86_64/
export AMDAPPSDKROOT="/home/roadeo/AMDAPPSDK-3.0"
export OPENCL_VENDOR_PATH="/home/roadeo/AMDAPPSDK-3.0/etc/OpenCL/vendors/"**
```

When i run `clinfo` to check whether OpenCL is installed properly or not. But I get this error:

```
**terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cl::Error'
what(): clGetPlatformIDs
Aborted core dumped.**
```

After googling I installed `fglrx` using `sudo apt-get`. When I run `clinfo` I get a lot of details about OpenCL versions, vendor etc.. I don't know whether is it required or not.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with AMD drivers on Linux, but it seems to me that installing the SDK only installed a bunch of examples, header files, etc. but did not actually install any OpenCL runtimes. Installing `fglrx` probably installed the CPU runtime, in which case the only device you'll see listed is your CPU. If you want to write OpenCL code for your GPU, you'll need to look at Beignet: https://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/Beignet/